# RegEx Search (Notepad++) - Return from character to character without specified characters between

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is it possible in RegEx; and if so how, to search from character to character only if specified characters are not included between them.

For instance:

```
Function
    {
        Parameter Parameter_Name
    }

Function
    {
    }
```

I want to run a search starting with "Function" and ending with "}" where "Parameter" does not appear between the two.

For reference, I am using Notepad++'s RegEx search, and I have ".matches newline" enabled, and have no trouble performing other multiline searches, I'm just not sure of the syntax.

I tried something along the lines of

```
Function.*!?Parameter.*?\}
```

But this search just caught everything between Function and the last "{" in the file. Meanwhile the below will always stop at the first "}" character.

```
Function.*?\}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Naive question, but can your function contain nested `{..}`?

Comment: What about `Function\s*\{\s*\}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive answer but hire it goes

```
 Function(?![^}]*\bParameter\b)[^}]*?\}
```

I assume that:

- your `Function` can't contain nested `{...}` blocks (at least no nested `}`)
- `Parameter` is separate word, so `Parameter_Name` will not be counted as `Parameter`.

`(?!...)` part is [negative-look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead).

`Function(?![^}]*\bParameter\b)` checks if after `Function` there is no `Parameter` which has no `}` before it. In other words it can have any other character beside `}` before which means that this `Parameter` will not be outside of currently checked `Function{...}` range. This means that negative-look-ahead will check only until it will find first `}` or end of your text.

Comment: Will add more info if it works. In case it doesn't work I can try to improve this regex, but will need example on which it fails.

Comment: This worked for me because I am not using nested {}s, it's exactly what I needed. In fact it worked even without "\b" which I took out in an attempt to reverse engineer how the search worked.

Comment: @DouglasMiller Should I add explanation or are you familiar with [look-around mechanism](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)?

Comment: Actually I lied, I just didn't know what it was called, based on the update you made to your answer, how your search works is abundantly clear. And I understand that the "\b" are being used in order to avoid situations where "Parameter" appears as part of a larger string.

Thanks for the explanation!